# NumberFormatException in BigDecimal to int or long(java)

Tags: numberformatexception

I am coding in Java,I want to transfer BigDecimal data to int or long, the data name is "recovered",its value is"889.0" and has the structure as follows:
[enter image description here][1]
I tried Long.valueOf(recovered.toString()) and Integer.valueOf(recovered.toString()),but both generate NumberFormatException.

I also tried recovered  recovered.toString().getBytes() and I got:
[enter image description here][2]

How can I have int or long value of "889.0"? 
Thank you.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GF3tD.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXNBb.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string `"889.0"` is not a valid format to convert to a `Long` or an `Integer`, it is a decimal format and you could convert it to a `Float` or a `Double`.

If you want an integer you could convert it to a float first and then use `Float.intValue` to convert it to an integer.

```
Float f = Float.valueOf(recovered.toString();
Integer i = f.intValue();
```